# How to identify which row is clicked and which list entry it maps to

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-1.1

I have the requirement to have 3 columns with a edit command link as fourth column in the data table. The columns can have duplicates values in many rows. The columns are editable input text field but will be disabled on load which has to be enabled on click of edit link. How best to identify which row edit link was clicked so appropriate row input text is enabled. We are using JSF 1.1 hence setpropertyactionlistner cannot be used.

To mark input text as enabled, i will also need to identify the row in arraylist which corresponds to the data table row link being clicked so that appropriate boolean flag can be set true for enabling input text.

Comment: You would have setPropertyActionListener in 1.2. According to the answer here there is no reason not to upgrade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710598/looking-for-java-source-of-jsf-1-1-implementation. JSF 1.1 is around 10 years old....

Comment: I provided the solution to move to 1.2, but no one is willing to take the risk. However have implemented a solution which is working fine now.